# How to set a protobuf message to a oneof struct

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Assuming I have this proto

```
message inner_body1{
    ... // some attr
}

message inner_body2{
   ... // some attr
}

message body {
    oneof inner{
    inner_body1 = 1;
    inner_body2 = 2;
    }
}

message head {
    ... // some attr
}

message pkg{
    head h = 1;
    body b = 2;
}
```

And I design a function like this

```
void SendPkg(proto::Message& data)
{
    pkg p;
    auto head = p.mutable_head();
    head->fillsomething();  // not important

    // My question is, if 'data' is definitely one of the message type defined in 'body'(e.g. 'inner_body1')
    // How can I put 'data' into pkg's body field?
}
```

My question is, if 'data' is definitely one of the message type defined in 'body'(e.g. 'inner_body1')
How can I put 'data' into pkg's body field?

update:
I have tried this way

```
void SendPkg(proto::Message& data)
{
    pkg p;
    auto head = p.mutable_head();
    head->fillsomething();  // not important

    auto body = p.mutable_body();
    const Descriptor* desc = data.GetDescriptor();
    if (desc.name() == "inner_body1")
    {
        auto body1 = body->mutable_innerbody1();
        body1.CopyFrom(data);
    }
    else
    {
        auto body2 = body->mutable_innerbody2();
        body2.CopyFrom(data);        
    }
}
```

this may works. But the fallback is obviously. I have to maintain this ugly string mapping and it running effienciency is low.

Is  there any way  could achieve this more  elegant?

Comment: There should be code generated with a setter function for each possible body type
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof

Comment: Why is the `SendPkg` parameter of type `Message` and not your `body` message type? Then you can also set it directly. You then simply create an instance of `body` with the proper `inner` field set, and call it with that.